# Value assignment inside if block in a VHDL process not working

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to implement something in VHDL. Code 1 gives a wrong output and I don't understand why.

```
process(Data_in, reset)
begin
  if(reset = '1') then
    sig_sel <= "00";
  elsif(reset = '0') then
    if(Data_in(0) = '1') then
      sig_sel <= "11";
      report "sig_sel a is: " & STD_LOGIC'image(sig_sel(0));
      report "sig_sel b is: " & STD_LOGIC'image(sig_sel(1));
      if(sig_sel = "11") then
        report "i am one and one";
      end if;
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

> Note: sig_sel a is: '0'
>   Note: sig_sel b is: '0'

But if I remove or comment the if statement after reset (as below - Code 2) it works!

```
process(Data_in, reset)
begin
  if(reset = '1') then
     sig_sel <= "00";
  elsif(reset = '0') then
    --if(Data_in(0) = '1') then
      sig_sel <= "11";
      report "sig_sel a is: " & STD_LOGIC'image(sig_sel(0));
      report "sig_sel b is: " & STD_LOGIC'image(sig_sel(1));
      if(sig_sel = "11") then
        report "i am one and one";
      end if;
    --end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

> Note: sig_sel a is: '1'
>   Note: sig_sel b is: '1'

This is strange to me as I need to do a couple of check before assigning `sig_sel` value. What could be wrong?

Comment: Is this a simulation or synthesis question?

Comment: The lines `if(reset = '1') then ... elsif (reset = '0') then` are tautological for synthesised code; the second part need only say `else`.

Comment: Thanks but isn't the main issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VHDL, assignments to signal becomes effective when the process ends (or it encounters a wait statement).

Thus,

```
sig_sel <= "11";
if sig_sel = "11" then
```

Will trigger the if only when `sig_sel` is `"11"` when entering the process, not everytime as you may expect from a computer programming standpoint.

The reason why it works for code2 (I can only guess, since you don't give all the relevant data) is that the code get executed twice. The first time when `reset` is deasserted (setting `sig_sel` to `"11"`), and the second time when `Data_in(0)` is assigned to `'1'` (triggering the if). I would expect you to get the following output though:

> Note: sig_sel a is: '0'
>   Note: sig_sel b is: '0'
>   Note: sig_sel a is: '1'
>   Note: sig_sel b is: '1'
>   Note: i am one and one

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan your observations are quite true. Any suggestion on how to implement the intended logic (in code 1) ?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the purpose of your intended logic, if you set a signal before comparing it's value, the comparaison is useless. Anyways, you could use variable instead of a signal, but I suggest newcomers to VHDL uses only signals. Signal behaviour acts like real life wire. It may takes time to get use to them, but that's part of the fun!